# Titanium Appcelerator Bluetooth module for Android & iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, titanium, appcelerator

Is there a free Bluetooth module for Titanium Appcelerator for iOS and Android Platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and also Logical Labs has released 2 Bluetooth modules for Titanium in the Appcelerator Marketplace

BT LE iOS module https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3834?2063287747

BT Classic Android module https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5221?259328472

These modules are not free, but you have trial version of these.

Answer (score 0):

there is a module available for ios, please go to this link.
https://github.com/smontgomerie/Appcelerator-iPhone-Bluetooth-Module

Thanks, 
PRASHAANTH